# Models for online markets with reputation system

Tags: game-theory, reference-request, dynamic-games, bayesian-game

The only relevant model I'm aware of is [Liu Qingmin(2011 R.E.S)](http://web.stanford.edu/group/siepr/cgi-bin/siepr/?q=system/files/shared/pubs/papers/pdf/06-30.pdf). Is there any other decent models dealing with the mechanism of online markets under reputation system, and perhaps linking to regulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you start by looking at

> C. Dellarocas. "The Digitization of Word-of-Mouth: Promise and
>   Challenges of Online Reputation Systems". *Management Science* 49
>   (10), October 2003, 1407-1424.

for a review of relevant literature and

> Friedman & Resnick "The Social Cost of Cheap Pseudonyms". *Journal of
>   Economcs and Management Strategy*. 10 (2), 173–199.

and

> "Sustainable Reputations with Rating Systems," 2011. Journal of
>   Economic Theory, 146, 2, 479-503

for some models of online reputation systems that comes to mind. If I think of any others, I will update this answer.